# Cannot write "i+2" as a post-condition in my for-each loop [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Can someone explain to me why i can write "i+2" as a post-condition while iterating through a List<> in a for-each loop, but have to write "i=i+2" while iterating through an Array?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i+2)
    {
        numbers[i] = 2;
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Because what is `i+2` going do achieve? The result of that addition is not saved anywhere. You need to assign it to `i` if you need the result.

Comment: `i+2` simply just evaluates the expression, but nothing is done with the answer of this expression. You need to update the value of `i` and this is done by using the `=` sign to reassign the value of `i`

Comment: Instead of `i=i+2`, you can write `i+=2`btw.

Comment: Thats neither a "for-each" loop nor a List<> - just a plain 1970s for loop over an array

Comment: **Please note that what you're iterating over is irrelevant.** It's the type of `for` statement you use that decides the syntax. You can iterate both `Array`s and `List`s using both the [basic `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) and the [enhaced `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Answer (score 3):

The [`ForUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) has to be a `StatementExpressionList`, i.e. a list of [`StatementExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression)s.

`i+2` is an expression, but not a statement expression.

Statement expressions can be informally (*) thought of as expressions which might have a side effect, and thus it makes sense for them to stand alone in a statement by themselves. `i+2` doesn't have a side effect, so there is no point in evaluating it.

---

(*) Informally, because `method1() + method2()` can have a side effect, because `methodN()` can have a side effect; and yet, it is not a statement expression because the "main" expression here - the addition - has no side effect in and of itself.

You could write this as `for (;; method1(), method2()) { ... }` (with no addition) if this was what you wanted in your `ForUpdate`.

Answer (score -2):

i+2 it's an expression, you have to assign a result to somewhere, so the correct syntax is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i=i+2)
{
    numbers[i] = 2;
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```